# Form is submitted despite the warning message

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a form (one text field and the submit button). The user input will be a 3-digit number and if the number is greater than `200` a warning will be displayed. If the user hits `OK` the form must be submitted but if he hits `CANCEL` then nothing happens and the user will be able to put some value again.

The fact is the my form is being submitted in any case (I can hardly notice the warning alert). Here is the code:

```
<form name="pontoi" action="update.php" method="post">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><br>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" onkeyup="checkInput(this)" maxlength="3" id="points" name="points"> 
            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                <button type="submit" id="prosthiki" onclick="checkInp(this)" class="btn btn-primary">ΠΡΟΣΘΗΚΗ</button> 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

```js
function checkInp(e) {
    var x = document.forms["pontoi"]["points"].value;
    var y = 200;
    if (x > y) {
        sweetAlert({
            title: "Number is over 200",
            text: "Are you sure?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you have any ideas on what form is being submitted in any case it would help me a lot.

There is also this script (I think it is better to use) but It doesn't work too..

```
$('.btn btn-primary').on('click',function checkInp(e){
e.preventDefault();
var form = $(this).parents('pontoi');

swal({
    title: "Number is over 200",
    text: "Are you sure?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "OK",
    closeOnConfirm: false
}, function checkInp(isConfirm){
    if (isConfirm) form.submit();
});
}
```

});

Answer (score 2):

You have to listen also for the onsubmit event of the form.

Stopping the event propagation from the button has no effect.

What you could do is hook directly to the submit event and not the button click

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(ev){

  var points = $("#points").val();

  if(points > 200) {
    // prevent form submission
    // will be submitted if the user clicks ok
    ev.preventDefault();

    sweetAlert({
      title: "Number is over 200",
      text: "Are you sure?",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "OK",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function checkInp(){
      //ev.target is the form submitted
      ev.target.submit();
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: I think this is what I need.But please if you could give me an example of the above it would be great.I am not aware of jQuery or Javascript..Thanks!

Comment: @platanas20 updated my answer to include your sample code

Comment: Thanks for that!But now there is no alert window and it passes any value I put on the text field.I use `onsubmit="return checkInp()"` on the the submit button

Comment: @platanas20 can you replicate your code on codepen.io/pen?

Comment: @platanas20 removed some inline javascript event listening which are absolete now. Just make sure you include the right sweetAlert plugin https://jsfiddle.net/97u4Lyj9/1/

Comment: Something goes wrong friend.I cannot understand what..It is ok!I don't want to bother you more.Thanks for everything!Regards!

Comment: @platanas20 https://jsfiddle.net/97u4Lyj9/2/ done with the native confirm dialog. So the only thing missing is the sweetAlert plugin hook

Comment: Ok i will check this out!Thanks a lot for your time.I appreciate it!